# Look Relative Movement in Unity using Cinemachine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm relatively new to coding, having just started about a week ago, and I can't seem to figure out or find anything relating to look relative movement using a third person Cinemachine freelook camera.

What I'm trying to accomplish is a camera similar to Risk of Rain 2, or *maybe* Smite where you can orbit the player and look at the front of them while they're idle, but once you start moving the player rotates towards the direction the camera is looking, and stays facing that direction no matter how they're moving.

I have a basic scene set up with a Cinemachine freelook camera following a cube, but my problem is whenever I turn the camera then move, my character doesn't rotate and instead starts moving in the direction it's facing instead of where the camera's looking, then only starts rotating if I'm pressing a movement key, so the rotation gets disjointed from where the camera's looking, if that makes sense. I kind of frankensteined some code from Royal Skies' movement tutorial and someone else's rotation tutorial for a top-down game.

This is the code for a script applied to my player character;

```
public float speed = 4.5f;
public Vector3 deltaMove;
public float turnspeed = 500;

void Update()
{
    deltaMove = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")) * speed * Time.deltaTime;  //movement code
    transform.Translate(deltaMove);

    float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) == true) //if wasd pressed, rotate
    {
        transform.Rotate(horizontal * turnspeed * Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime, Space.World); //the rotation code
    }
}
```

I'd be willing to do anything to be honest, I've been trying to figure this out for a bit now.

Comment: Well if you know where the camera is facing. What have you tried to apply that